# Can enum be used to type an array

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if there is a way to use an enum to describe the valid types an array can contain. I have yet to find a way to make this happen, is it possible?

Here's the example I have attempted:

```
interface User {
    name: string;
}

interface Admin {
    level: number;
}

enum Person {
    User,
    Admin,
}

const persons: Person[] = [
    { name: 'hello' },
    { level: 1 },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDcuAvrrqJLIigIIAmJUDnyEANhABuEUZRABXEgCNoTVrgjySyAArR0AexDDCaTFAA0Igv0EhLahIerIADnqeVdUAyADaAXWQAXmRfKxwiUgpkAHIAC2lRfRjkZksTbGRxKRlkAEZUy38mIA)

---

Something similar is possible with a union, just to clarify what I'm trying to achieve:

```
interface User {
    name: string;
}

interface Admin {
    level: number;
}

type Person = User | Admin;

const persons: Person[] = [
    { name: 'hello' },
    { level: 1 },
];
```

Comment: Try defining Person as base interface and derive User and Admin from it. Enums won't let you declare something like you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Eldar, although if I do that it wouldn't be an enum

Comment: I fail to understand what is the underlying reason why you would want to achieve something, that you can already achieve with union type, but with an enum which is not designed for this in Typescript? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: For sure, @Valentin. I'm still elaborating on my TS knowledge, my understanding is that TS can do exhaustive enum checks, but not on unions. So it can be useful in any fn that accepts a `Person` and needs to switch over the types.

Comment: Maybe this should be explained in the question too. But enums in Typescript are only usable for constant values, unlike in some other programming languages, so it's not gonna be the solution.

Comment: When you say switch over the types, do you mean using `switch/case`? Because that will never work with your interfaces...

Comment: Another reason is that I don't like the way I have to check whether the object I'm passing to a fn is a `User` or `Admin`, the `as` control https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDcuAvrrqJLIigIIAmJUDnyEANhABuEUZRABXEgCNoTVrjABPAA4oACtHQB7EMgC8aTFGQAfZP0EgmuBMerIdUIyHSV9n4wDaALpmyAEiBNhEpBTIAOQAFtKihnHIzAA0ETjI4lIyyACM6VlBTjByIAhgwMZUcBoAEsAAFB5evgbGAJTChMjAMMgtbV0mcOgW0N0AdMRkvXj9-S7ehuIzKXQj7XUTU1Cz8xDdTP3MyNKYfcsEq0Yb0FCGUC1xAHKG0WRxp9mszCAA

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Interesting. Maybe I'm looking for a unicorn here. Was hoping to find something similar to Rust's `match` expression in TypeScript :)

Comment: I think you have to come to terms first with the fact that interfaces are only compile-time constructs. You can't base run-time behavior on an interface type. If it were classes, you have some more options, but you still won't be able to use that enum-approach.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Makes sense. I assumed that was solved by TS assigning a name to each key in the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums can be used to define a set of named constants, and these can be used by Typescript as a type to limit a parameter to only the values of that enum.

If you want to define a set of possible types, like in your first code snippet, you should use unions, as you have done in your second code snippet.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.htm
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: Thanks, Luke. It seems like I've been looking for a unicorn :)